# Li's lose their position...

Tags: html, css

My HTML:

```
 <ul class="down_rectangles">
   <li >       
     <div class="keimeno">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec facilisis  
       consequat tellus consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec
      </div>

  </li>
  <li >
     <div class="keimeno">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec facilisis  
       consequat tellus
      </div> 

  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS follows:

```
.down_rectangles{   
list-style: none;
margin-top:0px; 
padding:0;  
}
.down_rectangles li {
height: 250px;
width: 265px;
background-color: #FFF;
display: inline-block;
margin-right:15px;
}
.down_rectangles>li:last-child {
margin-right:0;               
}
.keimeno{
color: #626262;
font-size: 12px;
margin: 20px;
line-height: 1.5em;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
```

If the text inside the two li's is the same they stand nice next to each other. Every time I tried to change the text inside the first li the second li is moving down a bit and losing its initial position . Why that happens?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a `vertical-align:top` to your `li` elements, since they are `inline-blocks`

example on codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vhJpG

Answer (score 6):

Because you are using `display: inline-block;` the elements are aligned to the `baseline` by default

So you need to use `vertical-align: top;` for `.down_rectangles`

```
.down_rectangles li {
    height: 250px;
    width: 265px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right:15px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/QLAhc/)

<s>[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/QLAhc/1/)</s> *(Sets to baseline if not used `vertical-align: top;`)*

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
.down_rectangles li{float :left;}
```