# Align inline-block DIVs to top of container element

Tags: css

When two `inline-block` `div`s have different heights, why does the shorter of the two not align to the top of the container? ([**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/RHM5L/7/)):

```css
.container { 
    border: 1px black solid;
    width: 320px;
    height: 120px;    
}

.small {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40%;
    height: 30%;
    border: 1px black solid;
    background: aliceblue;    
}

.big {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px black solid;
    width: 40%;
    height: 50%;
    background: beige;    
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="small"></div>
    <div class="big"></div>
</div>
```

How can I align the small `div` at the top of its container?

Comment: or float them like so: http://jsfiddle.net/RHM5L/12/

Comment: [Take a look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22064029/lis-lose-their-position/22064075#22064075)

Comment: apply vertical-align:top; for .small class

Comment: i don't want to use float. thanks @Mr.Alien it works now :)

Answer (score 453, accepted):

Because the `vertical-align` is set at *baseline* as default.

Use `vertical-align:top` instead:

```
.small{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40%;
    height: 30%;
    border: 1px black solid;
    background: aliceblue;   
    vertical-align:top; /* <---- this */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lighty_46/RHM5L/9/

Or as [@f00644](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22092724/make-to-div-start-at-the-same-level?noredirect=1#comment33508693_22092724) said you could apply `float` to the child elements as well.

Comment: If i apply the float i will have a problem in height if the container have just float childrens like in my case. Take a look here [**article**](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)

Comment: Any idea why `baseline` is the default? I'm sure there's a good reason, but to a non-expect it just seems weird. You end up with a Manhattan skyline effect.

Comment: Vertical align is used for font alignment, since fonts have baseline, it's just logical that the default resolves to baseline. In other occasions like this one, you have to overwrite it.

Answer (score 30):

You need to add a `vertical-align` property to your two child div's.

If `.small` is always shorter, you need only apply the property to `.small`.
However, if either could be tallest then you should apply the property to both `.small` and `.big`.

```
.container{ 
    border: 1px black solid;
    width: 320px;
    height: 120px;    
}

.small{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40%;
    height: 30%;
    border: 1px black solid;
    background: aliceblue; 
    vertical-align: top;   
}

.big {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px black solid;
    width: 40%;
    height: 50%;
    background: beige; 
    vertical-align: top;   
}
```

Vertical align affects inline or table-cell box's, and there are a large nubmer of different values for this property. Please see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align for more details.

Answer (score -1):

### Use `display: flex` property for the parent `div`

**The flexbox items are aligned at the start of the cross-axis.
By default, the cross-axis is vertical. This means the flexbox items will be aligned vertically at the top.**

**See the following code:**

```css
.container {
  border: 1px black solid;
  width: 320px;
  height: 120px;
  display: flex;
  /** CSS flex */
}

.small {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%;
  height: 30%;
  border: 1px black solid;
  background: aliceblue;
}

.big {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px black solid;
  width: 40%;
  height: 50%;
  background: beige;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="small"></div>
  <div class="big"></div>
</div>
```

**Browser Compatibility:** *Flexbox is very well supported across modern browsers.*

Comment: *it sets its child elements with vertical-align: top.* --> this is false, vertical-align no more apply to flex items.

Answer (score -2):

Add overflow: auto to the container div. 
http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html This website shows a few options when having this issue.

Answer (score -2):

```
<style type="text/css">
        div {
  text-align: center;
         }

         .img1{
            width: 150px;
            height: 150px;
            border-radius: 50%;
         }

         span{
            display: block;
         }
    </style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type='password' class='secondInput mt-4 mr-1' placeholder="Password">
  <span class='dif'></span>
  <br>
  <button>ADD</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$('button').click(function() {
  $('.dif').html("<img/>");

})
```

Comment: I think simply changing the default display properties of a span from inline to block will do the trick.