# CSS, how to align a button vertically next to large images

Tags: html, css

I want to vertically align a button to the right of an image.  This is the code:

```
<div style = "display:inline-block;width:250px;height:200px;border:2px solid">
</div>

<div style = "display:inline-block;width:250px;height:200px;border:2px solid">
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" style = "display:inline-block;">
```

This is the result:
[image]

The button appears in the lower right of the div tag. What I want is for it to appear in the top right of the div tag.  How can I do this?

Comment: `vertical-align:top`

Comment: Do you mean top right corner of inside the last div tag? or outside/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Align inline-block DIV's to top of container element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22092724/align-inline-block-divs-to-top-of-container-element)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Set the vertical-align property of the input to top:

```css
input {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div style="display:inline-block;width:250px;height:200px;border:2px solid"> </div>
<div style="display:inline-block;width:250px;height:200px;border:2px solid"> </div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" style="display:inline-block;">
```

Comment: If you have a problem with a *person*, please do everyone a favor and refrain from voting on their posts. Votes should be anchored on the merits of a post, not the user posting it, regardless of what you perceive their intentions may be.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers are good but you are missing one thing. If you set the class style to all inputs then they all will be aligned like that. If you will have more than 1 button then you have to use the follow code example:

```
.the_button {
    vertical-align:top;
    width: 100px; height:50px;
    display:inline-block;
    border:2px solid;
        background:#ffffff; 
    color:#000000;
}
```

Set a class like "the_button" for only this button and call it like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div style = "display:inline-block;width:250px;height:200px;border:2px solid"> </div>
    <div style = "display:inline-block;width:250px;height:200px;border:2px solid"> </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="the_button">
</div>
```

I created a good demo just for you amigo

http://jsfiddle.net/yyL3845e/2/

Comment: Please don't use classnames starting with "the", "my", or anything like that. It quickly devolves into `my_theButton-73` and then nobody can read your code. :(

Comment: @ssube heh, I'm sure that was just for the sake of the sample code =D

Comment: It is just a example for him. I would call it buttons-top-aligned but the class name is not important here but help other people. Or will you guys start fighting like you did with j08691? Then you are missing the point here and you are on the wrong site

Comment: Jhawins please chill out. You are annoying and disturbing and missing the point. I will not accep your answer edit because your edit is wrong. Can some admin or mod please tell him to chill out? Your edit sucks and you misslead the viewers with wrong answers

Answer (score -1):

You need to vertical-align the button.

```
input[type="submit"] {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yyL3845e/