# align div inline with container div

Tags: html, css

I found [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/RHM5L/7/) from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22092724/align-inline-block-divs-to-top-of-container-element) , but now I'm trying to align another div `class="new"` to be inline and outside the `container div` . I have tried to use `vertical-align:top`, `float`,`display: inline-block` but they didn't work.
What am I missing ?

This is what I'm trying to do.
HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="small"></div>
    <div class="big"></div>
</div>
<div class="new"></div>
```

CSS

```
.container{ 

    border: 1px black solid;
    width: 320px;
    height: 120px;    
    padding: 10px;
}

.small{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40%;
    height: 30%;
    border: 1px black solid;
    background: aliceblue;    
}

.big {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px black solid;
    width: 40%;
    height: 50%;
    background: beige;    
}
.new{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: gray;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: yeah it should be like that, that is what I tried but it didn't work

Comment: i have added my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to apply `display:inline-block` and `vertical-align:top` to both the `container` and `new` divs.

```css
.container {
  border: 1px black solid;
  width: 320px;
  height: 120px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.small {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 40%;
  height: 30%;
  border: 1px black solid;
  background: aliceblue;
}
.big {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px black solid;
  width: 40%;
  height: 50%;
  background: beige;
}
.new {
  height: 120px;
  width: 80px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="small"></div>
  <div class="big"></div>
</div>
<div class="new">
  new box
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container{ 
    
    border: 1px black solid;
    width: 320px;
    height: 120px;    
    
}

.small{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40%;
    height: 30%;
    border: 1px black solid;
    background: aliceblue;    
}

.big {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px black solid;
    width: 40%;
    height: 50%;
    background: beige;    
}

.new {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px black solid;
    width: 10%;
    height: 50%;
    background: yellow;    
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="small"></div>
    <div class="big"></div>
    <div class="new"></div>
</div>
```

I don't see your problem. It works fine.

Comment: no, the `.new div` should be outside the `.container div`

Answer (score 0):

a solution is to float the container to the left:

```css
.container{ 
    
    border: 1px black solid;
    width: 320px;
    height: 120px;    
    float: left;
    
}

.small{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40%;
    height: 30%;
    border: 1px black solid;
    background: aliceblue;    
}

.big {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px black solid;
    width: 40%;
    height: 50%;
    background: beige;    
}

.new {
    height: 120px;
    width: 80px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="small"></div>
    <div class="big"></div>
</div>
<div class="new">
    new box
</div>
```

Comment: @Ringo - You mentioned you tried applying `display:inline-block` to `.container` but didn't work. that should have worked fine

Comment: with `display:inline-block` `.container` will be on the left side, I dont want that, so I used it to `.new`, but it doesn't work

Comment: no, sorry I didn't make it clear, I want the container to be at the middle