# Balance the block in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I am new in HTML/CSS. I have a problem when designing my website.

Take a look:

[image]

I have 2 blocks and I wanna write something different on every block. How can I remove the blank space I've marked on the picture above.

Here is my code:

```
CSS
.blocks{
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 15px 0 0;
  border: none;
  color: black;
  background: #ff6f29;
  width: 30%;
}
.wrap{
    width: 100%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class= 'wrap'>
<div class= 'blocks'>
Some code
</div>
<div class= 'blocks'>
<p>text text text text</p>
<p>text text text text</p>
<p>text text text text</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yjn1qdoy/

Comment: If not floats then check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22092724/align-inline-block-divs-to-top-of-container-element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hi now define your  `class` `.blocks` `vertical-align:top;` as like this

```
.blocks{vertical-align:top;}
```

**[what is vertical-align](https://css-tricks.com/what-is-vertical-align/)**

Comment: Thank you! Super fast reply.

Answer (score 1):

just use floats:

```
.blocks{
  margin: 15px 0 0;
  border: none;
  color: black;
  background: #ff6f29;
  width: 30%;
    float:left;
    margin:5px;
    padding:5px;
}
.wrap{
    width: 100%;
    float:left;
}
```

Hers fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g5LgyLjg/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `float: left;` to the `.blocks` css.

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/66u1kz3n/)