# my div is in the wrong vertical position

Tags: html, css

i have two divs and im trying to have them both sit at the top to be next to eachother, but the second one with the dummy text is halfway down the page for some reason, and i cant get it to the top like the first div. here is some code i have

```
<div id="bgdsply2" style="width:300px; display:inline-block;">
        <img src="admin/showroom/clocks/thumbnails/bru4.jpg" width="300px" height="800px" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div style="width:300px; margin-left:200px; display:inline-block;">
        Quo ne facer impedit euripidis, inermis nonumes vis ex, fabulas menandri postulant ad nam. Animal disputationi ad qui, case natum cotidieque ei mel, et diam prima posse vel. Usu admodum lobortis inciderint eu, oratio tritani et vis, ea eum nemore deseruisse. Dicam conceptam interpretaris sed ea. Ex mei everti abhorreant disputationi.
    </div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Align inline-block DIV's to top of container element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22092724/align-inline-block-divs-to-top-of-container-element)

Comment: Add "float: left" to the first. Is this what you want - https://jsfiddle.net/ddk6gxt7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the width of the containing div and make sure that it can support both div's stacked side by side. Some people prefer to add `float: right;` to both divs and a `clear: both;` tag at the end so that the single space doesn't increase the divs width beyond 600px;

```
<div class='container' style='width: 600px;'>
    <div class='right' style='float: right; display: inline-block; width: 300px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;'>
        // content
    </div>
    <div class='left' style='float: right; display: inline-block; width: 300px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;'>
        // content
    </div>
    <p style='clear: both;'></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the divs next to each other without space or enter inbetween. You have two fixed-width divs, with (I assume) the intention to exactly fill the width of a parent element. The space between the divs makes it just a little too wide for them to be next to each other.

```
<div id="bgdsply2" style="width:300px; display:inline-block;">
    <img src="admin/showroom/clocks/thumbnails/bru4.jpg" width="300px" height="800px" alt="" />
</div><div style="width:300px; margin-left:200px; display:inline-block;">
    Quo ne facer 
</div>
```