# How to align <form> elements vertically?

Tags: html, css, forms, element

I'm trying to make a copy of Google's search site from 2003 as a HTML exercise but I ran into a problem. I have finally managed to create an unordered list next to an input field but I don't want that text input to move alongside with the last item of the list as you can see below:

[image: My problem]

Could you tell me what I'm supposed to do in order to move that `<input>` field next to "Advanced search"?

This is my code:

```css
ul {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<form action="http://www.google.com/search" method="get">
<div style="text-align:center">
<input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search on Google"  style="width: 380px" >
<ul>
<li>Advanced search</li>
<li>Preferences</li>
<li>Language tools</li>
</ul>
</div>
</form>
```

[My whole code](https://code.sololearn.com/WIbV1C63rtrF/#html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply a `vertical-align: top;` to your `input` by adding this to your CSS:

```
input {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Here's an example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z23k531y/)

`inline-block` elements will align to the bottom of their container because the default for `vertical-align` is `baseline`. By instead applying `vertical-align: top`, the element will align itself with the top of its container.

---

I'm realizing now it may have been a better decision to instead mark this question as a duplicate. Your question is nearly identical to the one seen here: [Align inline-block DIV's to top of container element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22092724/align-inline-block-divs-to-top-of-container-element)

Consider reading this for a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

hello you can do this simply by adding extra css

```
 float:right;
 margin-top:auto;
```

see below hope it helps.

```css
ul {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  float:right;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top:auto;
}
```

```html
<form action="http://www.google.com/search" method="get">
<div style="text-align:center">
<input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search on Google"  style="width: 380px" >
<ul>
<li>Advanced search</li>
<li>Preferences</li>
<li>Language tools</li>
</ul>
</div>
</form>
```