# CSS divs not horizontally aligned properly

Tags: html, css, alignment, contacts

This is probably a stupid question, but it has been driving me crazy the whole day. I need both divs with the class of `contacthor` to be aligned on the top, but not forcing them by using `margin-top: -x` or etc. [Here is an image of the issue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGug1.jpg)

Also, Im new to web design so if I have useless code please explain.

Thanks.

```css
#redcontact {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 5vh;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 30px;
  background: black;
}

.contacthor {
  display: inline-block;
}

form > .contacthor > .input {
  color: #C5B358;
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: black;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 1vh;
  margin-bottom: 1vh;
  height: 30px;
  width: 190px;
  display: block;
}

.contacthor > textarea {
  color: #C5B358;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  width: 60vh;
  height: 25vh;
  background: black;
  border: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-color: grey;
  padding-left: 4px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1vh;
  margin-left: 1vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="redcontact">
  <form action="action_page.php">
    <div class="contacthor">
      <label for="name">Nombre</label>
      <input class="input" type="text" name="name_user" placeholder="test">
      <label for="org">Empresa</label>
      <input class="input" type="text" name="org" placeholder="test">
      <label for="mail">Mail</label>
      <input class="input" type="text" name="mail" placeholder="contacto@test.com">
    </div>
    <div class="contacthor">
      <p>Mensaje</p>
      <textarea name="mensaje" tabindex="5" placeholder="text..."></textarea>
      <input type="submit" value="enviar">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Use flexbox. Put display: flex on your form element and it will be top aligned by default!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would agree with Chere's answer in that you should be using something like [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) or [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox). However, if you want to stay simple for this example, or just want to know why your code isn't working, here is a solution:

```css
#redcontact {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 5vh;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 30px;
  background: black;
}

.contacthor {
  display: inline-block;
}

form>.contacthor>.input {
  color: #C5B358;
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: black;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 1vh;
  margin-bottom: 1vh;
  height: 30px;
  width: 190px;
  display: block;
}

.contacthor>textarea {
  color: #C5B358;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  width: 60vh;
  height: 25vh;
  background: black;
  border: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-color: grey;
  padding-left: 4px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1vh;
  margin-left: 1vh;
}

.contacthor>p {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1vh;
  margin-left: 1vh;
}

.contacthor>input[value=enviar] {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1vh;
  margin-left: 1vh;
}

/* ===== Styles to fix example ===== */

label, p {
  color: white;
}

/* ===== Styles to answer your question ===== */

.contacthor {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div id="redcontact">
  <form action="action_page.php">
    <div class="contacthor">
      <label for="name">Nombre</label>
      <input class="input" type="text" name="name_user" placeholder="test">
      <label for="org">Empresa</label>
      <input class="input" type="text" name="org" placeholder="test">
      <label for="mail">Mail</label>
      <input class="input" type="text" name="mail" placeholder="contacto@test.com">
    </div>
    <div class="contacthor">
      <p>Mensaje</p>
      <textarea name="mensaje" tabindex="5" placeholder="text..."></textarea>
      <input type="submit" value="enviar">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

The main thing to take away from this is the addition of `vertical-align: top`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22092724/align-inline-block-divs-to-top-of-container-element) is a similar question and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) is the documentation for the `vertical-align` property.

Note: I think there may have been some CSS missing, so the snippet looks a bit odd and I had to make a couple of unrelated changes.

Answer (score 1):

Why is there a . before the input? 
Also, I highly recommend not using vh or pixels. You should go with em. Without doing everything, you should probably try to do something like that, with flexbox.

```
#redcontact {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
 }

form {
  display: flex;
  padding: 2em;

  .contacthor {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 0 2em;

    input,
    textarea {
      color: #C5B358;
      background-color: transparent;
      margin-left: 1em;
      margin-bottom: 1em;
      padding: 0.5em 1em;
      width: auto;
      display:block;
    }

    input {
      border: 0;
    }

    textarea {
      border: 1px solid grey;
      border-radius: 3px;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have made a grid. See if you are looking for somewhat similar thing.
https://codepen.io/kalpeshshende/pen/qJjomO

```
form{
  display:grid;grid-gap:10px;
  grid-template-columns:1fr 2fr;
}
.holder{
    max-width:600px;
    margin:auto;
    background:black;
    color:#C5B358;padding:10px;
}
.contacthor{
  display:grid;grid-gap:10px;
}
textarea{
  height:100px;
}
input[type=submit]{
  width:120px;

}
p{
  padding:0px;
}
input[type=text]{
  background:black;
  color:;border:none;
}
```

Markup :

```
<body>
    <div class="holder">
    <form action="">
       <div class="contacthor">
           <label for="name" >Nombre</label>
          <input class="input" type="text" name="name_user" placeholder="test">
        <label for="org">Empresa</label>
          <input class="input" type="text" name="org" placeholder="test">
        <label for="mail">Mail</label>
          <input class="input" type="text"  name="mail" placeholder="contacto@test.com">
      </div>
        <div class="contacthor">
          <label for="Mensaje">Mensaje</label>
          <textarea name="mensaje" tabindex="5" placeholder="text..."></textarea>
          <input type="submit" value="enviar">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try adding `vertical-align: top;` to `contracthor`.